# SQLAlchemy Error When Adding Item to Table

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am trying to run the following simple operation to update entries of a SQL Table with sqlite:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import update

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///tests.db", echo=True)

session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "usertable"
    username = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    password = Column(String)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

user = User()
user.username = "John"
user.password = "pass"
session.add(user)
session.commit()

stmt = update(User).where(User.c.password == 'pass').values(password='PASSWORD')
session.execute(stmt)
session.commit()
```

But when I run this I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'c'

Can someone please clarify the right way to do this?

Comment: Any particular reason you have used `User.c`?

Comment: I was trying to follow the guide here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_update.html#the-update-sql-expression-construct

Comment: @HarshSaini If I don't add .c and then print the contents, the password does not get updated.

Comment: Add `session.flush()` after adding the user data.

Comment: I have also tried, but it still does not update the DB

Comment: Add `session.flush()` after `session.add()` not after update.

Comment: I just tried that too and it does not work. Also note that session.commit() always calls session.flush() so adding another one beforehand is not going to make a difference

Comment: The link you posted is for SQLAlchemy _core_, but you are using the _ORM_.  The code works if you remove `.c`.  The relevant tutorial docs are [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/orm_data_manipulation.html#orm-enabled-update-statements).

Comment: @snakecharmerb thank you so much, that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

As snakecharmerb mentioned, the ORM version does not require .c, and adding session.execute on the update statement will resolve the problem:

```
stmt = update(User).where(User.password == 'pass').values(password='PASSWORD')
session.execute(stmt)
session.commit()
```